# MVC - how to make the url not to change when a method is called

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I have

login controller,model and view

url http://mySite/login

Now when i am at http://mySite/controller it shows the login form and then when i submit the form the **run method** is called so the url change to  http://mySite/login/run

how can i stop this :?

P.S // I creat my own MVC following this tut : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Eu0Nkpo6vM

login controller

```
class Login extends Conroller  {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function index() 
    {   
        $this->view->render('authentication/enter');
    }

    function run()
    {
        $this->model->run();
    }


}
```

login model

```
class Login_Model extends Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function run()
    {

            $sth = $this->dbh->connect()->prepare("SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE 
                username = :login ");
        $sth->execute(array(':login' => $_POST['login']));

        $data = $sth->fetch();

        $count =  $sth->rowCount();
        if ($count > 0) {
            // login
            Session::set('loggedIn', $_POST['login']);
            header('location: ../dashboard');
        } else {
            echo 4;
        }


    }

}
```

withour .htacces

the url is

http://mySite/index.php?url={controller name}

or

http://mySite/index.php?url={controller name}/{some method from the contoller}

Comment: please show some of your code so that we can figure out where's the redirect being made.

Comment: In the tut when u are in /index.php?url=login load the login controller who load the login model and view. Everething is working how is showed in the tutorial but the guy dosent show how to change the url

Answer (score 0):

Without watching that entire video or wondering too hard why you're re-inventing the PHP MVC wheel, here's my best guess.

1. Change your view's form to submit to the index action

   ```
   <form method="post" action="login" ...
   ```
2. In your index action, detect a POST request and run the model's `run()` method from there

   ```
   function index() 
   {   
       if ($this->request->isPost()) { // seriously, I'm just guessing here
           $this->model->run();
       }
       $this->view->render('authentication/enter');
   }
   ```

A couple of notes...

- Don't do controller tasks (ie redirecting) from the model
- Always `exit;` after sending a `Location` response header
- Drop this mess and try a proven and tested MVC framework like Symfony or Zend

Comment: oop yes <form method="post" action="login/run" .. but still this is ugly. When i just want to learn the basic and the logic but who is better codiigneeter or symfony or zend ?

Comment: @MarianPetrov I'm liking Symfony 2 right now but that's just my opinion